# Discrete Math on Recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a $1 \times n$ chessboard. a) Suppose we can color each square of the chessboard either black or white at random. Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to color the chessboard so that no two white squares are adjacent. Find a recurrence relation for $a_n$ . b) Repeat part a) if instead of each square can be colored red, white, or black.

I know this problem relates to recurrence, but I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for a, an $n$ length coloring can be an $n-1$ length coloring with a black square added, or an $n-2$ length coloring with a black and a white added.  Can you apply that to b?